# Having a dilemma with iterator and jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator

I have a problem with this iterator....it won't get the index of the iterator so that i can put in an "if"...it goes directly to else...i think i'm not getting the index properly but i don't know how...please help if you can

```
 <s:iterator  value="fileNames" status="idx">
   <s:set name="index" value="#idx.index"/> 
            <s:if test="%(#index)=4" >
        <div id="ngg-image-01"  class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
        <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <a id="1" rel="prettyPhoto[set_1]"                                                                      
                 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userfiles/images/inside/7-  
                 days/prettyPhoto[set_1]/<s:property/>" alt="<s:property/>"><br />
                <img title="revederepensiune-vara-02"                                         
         src="userfiles/images/inside/7-days/prettyPhoto[set_1]/thmbs/<s:property/>" 
        alt="" width="89" height="66" /><br /></a></div>
                                </div> 
            </s:if>

              <s:else> 
                <div id="ngg-image-01" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
        <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <a id="1" rel="prettyPhoto[set_1]" 
           href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userfiles/images/inside/7-
           days/prettyPhoto[set_1]/<s:property/>" alt="<s:property/>"><br /> 
      <img title="revederepensiune-vara-02"
     src="userfiles/images/inside/7-days/prettyPhoto[set_1]/thmbs/<s:property/>" 
     alt="" width="89" height="66" /><br /></a></div>
                                </div> 
              </s:else>              




     </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your JSP pages properly. Not doing so makes it much more difficult for you, and everybody else, to comprehend what's actually happening. Almost all IDEs and text editors will help you do this automatically--there's no excuse.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the `<s:if` tag is wrong. Change the test attribute - the brackets should be curly braces and the `=` should be `==`, as shown below:

```
<s:if test="%{#index==4}" >
```

Comment: +1 but note, with current versions of struts2 I think 'index == 4' should be all that is required. That is no need for # and the test is evaluated by default so %{} is not required.